# Pragma Exception init with constant

Tags: oracle, plsql

I store the error codes my stored procedures may throw (by calling raise_application_error) as constants. One of my procedures has to catch the error another one throws, and I am trying to do this with pragma exception_init. 
It seems that it only accepts numeric literals (as it explicitly says so in the error message I get), but it would be great to be able not to hardwire the error codes I otherwise store in constants. Is there some workaround for this, so that I could achieve the same as if I wrote:

> pragma exception_init(myException, pkg_constants.error_not_null);

Comment: You get PLS-00103 if you try to refer to the package variable directly; and PLS-00702 if you use a local variable (set the package variable), right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the package constant, or any variable, in the pragma.

What you could do is define the exception itself and its associated pragma in your package:

```
create package pkg_constants as
  MyException exception;
  error_not_null constant pls_integer := -20001;
  pragma exception_init(myException, -20001);
end pkg_constants;
/
```

You still have to repeat the error number, but at least only in the same file. You can then refer to that package-defined exception in a handler without having to redeclare it:

```
exception
  when pkg_constants.MyException then
    ...
```

For example:

```
set serveroutput on
begin
    raise_application_error(pkg_constants.error_not_null, 'Threw it');
exception
  when pkg_constants.MyException then
    dbms_output.put_line('Caught it');
    raise;
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-20001: Threw it
ORA-06512: at line 6

Caught it
```